# How to create a Azure Data Factory Linked service to connect with private Azure Data Explorer using private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have to create a linked service in Azure Data Factory which connects to private Azure Data Explorer using private end point.

In Azure Data Explorer, I have restricted public access and created a private endpoint on it.

In Azure Data Factory, I have performed below steps:

1. Created Integrated Runtime with virtual network enabled.
2. Created managed private endpoint to connect ADX (same is approved under Azure Data Explorer private endpoint section).

Now, while creating a linked service, I cannot see any option to select private endpoint. But if I try to created a linked service for SQL server, then there is an option to select private endpoint.

So, I would like to know if ADF linked service can be connected to PRIVATE azure data explorer. If so, how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft ADF documentation, managed private endpoint connection is not supported from ADF to data explorer.
[image: ADF documentation]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview

Comment: Hi Chen. Thank you for your response. So there is no other way to access my private ADX ? Only way is to make my ADX public ?

Comment: You can install a self hosted integration runtime on a VM inside your private vnet, and access data explorer with it.

Comment: Hey Chen, one last question. I am new to this security part of Azure. 

Say if my Azure Data Factory and Azure Data Explorer are in same VNET. They still need private endpoint to connect. Am I Right ? Just want to confirm even though if they are in same VNET, they cannot be connect. Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the documentation shown above it looks like they cannot connect privately, unless you use self hosted integration runtime inside your data explorer vnet.

Answer (score 0):

Your Data Factory and Data Explorer will never be in the same vnet. It's Impossible. The only vnet where your Data Factory can be, is in it's own Managed vnet.